# How to change file permissions when booted from a live disk/stick

Tags: boot, permissions, fstab

Let me start by saying that I am new to Ubuntu so please forgive my inexperience.  Also, this question goes along with my question I posted on 5/15/2017 titled:  [Fstab edit crashed system.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915179/fstab-edit-crashed-system)

**THE PROBLEM**

I can not save the edit to my `/etc/fstab` file while booting from a live disk.

When I open the `/etc/fstab` file with gedit as root, this is the header information I see:

```
*fstab [Read-Only] (491 GB Volume /media/ubuntu/0823c4f5-e42b-45ee-97b8-ad5d424b8b
```

**MY QUESTION**

How can I change the file permission of  `/etc/fstab` file to read - write in order to allow me to edit and save it while booting from a live disk?

---

**EDIT UPDATE 5/21/2017**

I am trying to apply sudodus solution (Thank You) to my issue, and I am not positive on how to proceed. Below is the result of me running his code to Identify the partition:

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo lsblk -o model,size,name,fstype,label,mountpoint
MODEL     SIZE NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL                    MOUNTPOINT
TOSHIBA 465.8G sda                                     
      487M ├─sda1 ext2                             /media/ubuntu/99ee9dc0-67
        1K ├─sda2                                  
    465.3G └─sda5 LVM2_me                          
    457.3G   ├─ubuntu--vg-root
             │    ext4                             /media/ubuntu/0823c4f5-e4
        8G   └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1
                  swap                             
WDC WD1 931.5G sdb                                     
    931.5G └─sdb1                                  
ST4000D   3.7T sdc                                     
      128M ├─sdc1                                  
      3.7T └─sdc2 ext4    Seagate D1               /media/ubuntu/Seagate D1
ST4000D   3.7T sdd                                     
      128M ├─sdd1                                  
      3.7T └─sdd2 ext4    Seagate D2               /media/ubuntu/Seagate D2
DVD-ROM   1.4G sr0    iso9660 Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS amd64 /cdrom
      1.4G loop0  squashf                          /rofs
```

My next step would be to Mount the partition using the information above, which I believe I needed to mount sda5, so I ran the following:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
```

However, I then get the following:

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

**New Questions**

1. Is sda5 the correct mount point, and did I type the command correctly?
2. What is this unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'?

---

***EDIT UPDATE 5/22/2017***

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I was able to save my edit to my /etc/fstab file while booting from a live disk by following the comment left by @mook765, and then following the next steps suggested by @sudodus.

The partition I needed to mount was indeed a logical partition (LVM@_member). I was able to mount it with:

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /mnt
```

After that, I was able to edit and save the /etc/fstab file, which fixed the problem I had with my question I posted on 5/15/2017 titled:  [Fstab edit crashed system.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915179/fstab-edit-crashed-system)

A very huge **THANK YOU** to @mook765 and @sudodus for all of your help!  I do not think I could have gotten my system back up and running without it.

I will be researching and reading much more on how to edit the fstab file before trying this again.

Comment: The partition you want to mount is a logical partition (LVM@_member). Try to mount the partition with `sudo mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /mnt` and then follow the next steps suggested by @sudodus. If you can't mount the partition that way, take a look at the accepted answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339011/how-do-i-mount-an-lvm-partition .

Comment: I am not very experienced with LVM mapping, but looking at your output from `lsblk`, it seems to me, that the root partition is already mounted at `/media/ubuntu/0823c4f5-e4`

Comment: Are there still problems? The root partition seems mounted already. Can you find it? Is it read-write or read-only? If read-only, try to unmount it and then mount it according to the comment at your question by @mook765.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I booted from a [persistent] live drive and could edit `fstab` in an installed system (both systems are 16.04.1) according to the following dialogue.

- Identify the partition

  ```
  ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -o model,size,name,fstype,label,mountpoint
  MODEL              SIZE NAME        FSTYPE   LABEL                    MOUNTPOINT
  Samsung SSD 850  232.9G sda                                           
                     300M ├─sda1      vfat     EFI                      
                       1M ├─sda2                                        
                     100G ├─sda3      ext4     root                     
                       5G └─sda4      swap                              [SWAP]
                     1.4G loop0       squashfs                          /rofs
                    29.7G mmcblk0                                       
                       7G ├─mmcblk0p1 ntfs     usbdata                  /media/ubuntu/usbdata
                       1K ├─mmcblk0p2                                   
                     122M ├─mmcblk0p3 vfat     usbboot                  /media/ubuntu/usbboot
                     1.4G ├─mmcblk0p4 iso9660  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS amd64 /media/ubuntu/Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS amd64
                    21.1G └─mmcblk0p5 ext4     casper-rw                /media/ubuntu/casper-rw
  ```
- Mount the partition

  ```
  ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdxn /mnt
  ```

  where `x` is the drive letter and `n` is the partition number. In my case:

  ```
  ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
  ```
- List the file with the permissions

  ```
  ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ls -l /mnt/etc/fstab
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 717 Apr 30  2016 /mnt/etc/fstab
  ```
- Back it up

  ```
  ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo cp -p /mnt/etc/fstab /mnt/etc/fstab.bak
  ```
- Edit `/mnt/etc/fstab` with root (superuser) privileges

  ```
  ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo nano /mnt/etc/fstab
  ```
- Check versus the backup file

  ```
  ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo diff /mnt/etc/fstab /mnt/etc/fstab.bak
  14d13
  < # added this line for demo
  ```
- List the file and its backup file

  ```
  ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ls -l /mnt/etc/fstab*
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 744 May 20 15:54 /mnt/etc/fstab
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 717 Apr 30  2016 /mnt/etc/fstab.bak
  ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
  ```
- Comment: So the edit was successful. The modified version was written.

Comment: I am not sure how to fix the problem I am running into while trying to apply sudodus solution, could you please look at the questions in my edit update on 5/21/2017 and give advice.  Thank you.

Comment: @CraigTimmreck, are there still problems? The root partition seems mounted already. Can you find it? Is it read-write or read-only? If read-only, try to unmount it and then mount it according to the comment at your question by mook765.