# Stuck in boot: Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev) in BusyBox

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, permissions, directory

To solve a Wi-fi issue I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 from USB. After completing the installation process Ubuntu started rebooting. But it couldn’t complete reboot as it stuck in this error menu. Please help me to solve this problem.

BusyBox initramfs error:

Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)

ALEART! UUID=a41ee097-5069-408d-abbd-4f50848aa357 does not exit.

Laptop Model: Lenovo Ideapad S340-14IWL

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rcoH.jpg)

Comment: This indicates an issue with /etc/fstab. Boot the computer from a usb and fix the entries therein (it's a simple text file).

Comment: Can you kindly tell me the steps to fix the entries? Because I am a novice in Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't have time atm to write a detailed answer - perhaps someone else will - but /etc/fstab is a text file that associates the UUIDs of the partitions on your system with their mountpoints. An overview of the procedure is 1) boot to live USB 2) determine UUIDs of your partitions 3) edit /etc/fstab to show the correct UUIDs

Comment: I wish someone will give me the solution tutorial.

Comment: There is a step by step answer on how to boot from a live usb and edit fstab here https://askubuntu.com/a/917157/243321 You'll need to do a `sudo blkid` to figure out what the UUIDs are. If you can figure out which UUIDs should be in the fstab it should be easy to fix.

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely try the steps.