# Unable to boot after modifying fstab file 20.04LTS

Tags: boot, fstab

I recently upgraded from 18.04 LTS to 20.04LTS and was attempting to modify it per a YouTube video. I changed the `/etc/fstab` file by adding `noatime.` before the word "`errors`" (per video instruction to reduce SDD writes)

Now my system won't boot. I've tried to access root via 18.04 disk but I am not proficient enough to be successful after hours of searching and trying various things.

I did download and run boot repair: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BK7ZFYS4Nn/

How do I get access to my root drive to edit the fstab file? That's where I'm getting hung up. Can't get to the point where I'm asked for the password because I'm accessing via bootable disk.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ /dev/sdb1 /etc/fstab
bash: /dev/sdb1: Permission denied –

ran mount | grep '^/'

/dev/sr0 on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
/cow on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=//filesystem.squashfs,upperdir=/cow/upper,workdir=/cow/work)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_6350.snap on /snap/core/6350 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_818.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/818 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-26-1604_74.snap on /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-calculator_260.snap on /snap/gnome-calculator/260 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-characters_139.snap on /snap/gnome-characters/139 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-logs_45.snap on /snap/gnome-logs/45 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-system-monitor_57.snap on /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/sdb4 on /media/ubuntu/7306bbfd-e19f-4fc6-b44c-0724eac5e663 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt type ext2 (rw,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr,acl)
/dev/sdb2 on /mnt type ext4 (rw,relatime)

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ mount /dev/sdb1
mount: /dev/sdb1: can't find in /etc/fstab.

UPDATE: problem resolved. I was able to access the root drive via steeldriver's [previous post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915179/fstab-edit-crashed-system/915190#915190).
Using: sudo mount /dev/sdb1/mnt
then sudo nano /mnt/etc/fstab

Computer rebooted. THANK YOU!

Comment: mount options need to be separated by commas, like `noatime,errors=remount-ro` - it looks like you used a period `noatime.errors=remount-ro` (making the options invalid). This is probably something that's easiest fixed by booting a live USB, mounting the block device, and editing its `/etc/fstab` file from there.

Comment: I think you nailed it, steeldriver.  I'm quite the novice. How do I "mount the block device?   That is what I wanted to do. edit the fstab file, but was unable to get this information, mainly due to my ignorance of how to ask the correct question!

Comment: As above and a few additional comments: (1) *to reduce SDD writes*... This was often suggested more than 10 years ago when SSDs where a lot more expensive and less reliable. Modern SSDs are more likely to outlast the computer itself, no special "care" needed. (2) Boot-Repair is NOT for your self/inflicted problem. Many user unfortunately think of it as an universal panacea but in reality it has a very narrow usage. Please do NOT spam their mailbox

Comment: Thanks ChanganAuto. I did not know any of what you told me except I have a self-inflicted problem.

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ /dev/sdb1 /etc/fstab
bash: /dev/sdb1: Permission denied

Comment: For mounting/editing instructions see for example [Fstab edit crashed system](https://askubuntu.com/a/915190/178692)

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: Thank you steeldriver. How do I get access to my root drive? That's where I'm getting hung up. Can't get to the point where it's asking me for the password because I'm accessing via bootable disk