# systemd: Failed to start Remount Root and Kernel File Systems

Tags: boot, partitioning, kernel, mount, steam

I was trying to get Proton for Steam working. After a long time search tech forums I found a comment which said that Proton had to be formatted to EXT4, which led me down a rabbit hole to a post on the Steam forums which said to go into the Disks app and put `,uid=1000,gid=1000` after a string of commands in the mount settings of the disk partition Steam was in.

I did that and now my machine is pretty much screwed. I turned it on and it says:

```
[    2.704762] hid-generic 0003:1532:0099.0004: No inputs registered, leaving /dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 428432/31227904 files, 10823956/124895488 blocks
[    3.261244] ext4: Unknown parameter ‘uid’
[    3.266616] systemd[1]: Failed to start Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[FAILED] Failed to restart Remount Root and File Systems.
[    3.279284] systemd[1]: Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
[FAILED] Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Swaps.
[     3.649651] ext4: Unknown parameter ‘uid’
[     3.677364] ext4: Unknown parameter ‘uid’
```

I am a complete Linux noob. I have no idea what I'm doing.
Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Starting point for understanding how to clearly help, is what OS & release you're using.  What Ubuntu product are you using? and what release of that product?  You can usually fix *file-system table* issues easily by booting a *live* media & reversing your change(s) from there.

Comment: @guiverc I don’t know what version or release it’s on, just that it’s Ubuntu. What’s a live media?

Comment: *live* media is the media you install from; you have options on booting it to either *Try* or *Install* (*what is offered varies of course on product & release of which you gave no specific details*). Here by using *live* I mean using the *Try* mode which has the system run *live* allowing you to mount your installed system, and make any adjustments there that are required.

Comment: @guiverc OK I’ll try that out and see if I can reset the startup settings. My brother is more experienced with Linux than I am (he runs Mint instead of Ubuntu though) so I’ll ask him for help on it. Thanks for the advice. Will update post if problem is solved

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fstab edit crashed system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915179/fstab-edit-crashed-system)